# SQL Server UPDATE - GROUP BY - MAX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-update, max

This is SQL Server 2016. I have the following data in only one table:

```
custID  | prodID | title  | titleCount  | isMasterTitle
--------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------
  266   | 191750 | prod01 |      1      | 0
  266   | 191750 | prod02 |      4      | 0
  266   | 191750 | prod03 |     25      | 0
  300   |  20125 | prod04 |      3      | 0
  300   |  20125 | prod05 |     15      | 0
```

I want to group by custID, prodID and title and update isMasterTitle field to 1 for every max() titleCount per group.

So, I want the following:

```
custID  | prodID | title    | titleCount | isMasterTitle
--------+--------+----------+------------+---------------
  266   | 191750 | prod01   |     1      |     0
  266   | 191750 | prod02   |     4      |     0
  266   | 191750 | prod03   |    25      |     1
  300   |  20125 | prod04   |     3      |     0
  300   |  20125 | prod05   |    15      |     1
```

I'm trying the following:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[_Variations]
SET isMasterTitle = 1
FROM [dbo].[_Variations]  v1
INNER JOIN (SELECT custID, prodID, MAX(titleCount) AS mtitleCount 
            FROM [_Variations] 
            GROUP BY custID,prodID) as v2 ON v1.custID = v2.custID and v1.prodID = v2.prodID and v1.titleCount = v2.mtitleCount
```

Comment: And what happens when titlecount has the same max value for 2 different rows within the same group?

Comment: Good question. I'm not expecting to have the same max value. This is about a repeating product title in a big dataset. Usually, about 90% of product title instances are correct and about 10% wrong. I'm trying to determine the correct ones using the above percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
;with cte 
as
(
    select isMasterTitle, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by custID, prodID order by titleCount desc) rn
    from @t
)
update cte
set isMasterTitle = 1
where rn = 1

select * from @t
```

***Your given code also works fine.***

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05e12066a54124f76669f4613aa8d60d)**.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake in the above sample data. Now it's correct. Note that the title changes even for the same prodID. As it is, both queries result to 1 in all rows.

Comment: Oh... Got it. I just exclude 'title'. So this will work when titles are different:

    UPDATE @t
    SET isMasterTitle = 1
    FROM @t  v1
INNER JOIN (SELECT custID, prodID, MAX(titleCount) AS mtitleCount 
            FROM @t 
            GROUP BY custID,prodID) as v2 ON v1.custID = v2.custID and v1.prodID = v2.prodID and v1.titleCount = v2.mtitleCount

Comment: I'm modifying the code above for consistency. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You are right. I have also updated the answer and you should use updatable cte as suggested by "GMB" in another answer. Thanks, @GMB.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend leveraging a powerful feature of SQL Server called the *updateable common-table-expression*.

You can build a cte that uses window functions to identify which row should be updated, and then directly update it; there is no need to join again the original table in the outer query. This makes the query both shorter and more efficient:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        isMaster,
        row_number() over(partition by custID, prodID order by titleCount desc) rn
    from [dbo].[_Variations]
)
update cte set isMaster = 1 where rn = 1
```